# Forward Google Domain with masking to a squarespace page url which includes a path

Tags: dns, masking

I have holding page: www.yourssincerely.co/wbm (hosted by squarespace)

I have a domain: www.wanderingbarman.com (registered with google domains)

I would like to direct www.wanderingbarman.com, to the holding page but instead of displaying www.yourssincerely.co/wbm in the url bar, I'd like it to display www.wanderingbarman.com.

Masking a domain does not seem to be straight forward with google domains.

I found a question/answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273133/how-to-mask-the-domain-forward-from-google-domains-without-google-app) suggesting dynamic DNS as a solution and I tried to follow it to no avail.

This is how my dns/cname settings appear

[image].

I'm sure it's a simple fix, I'm just clueless. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you